# Questions about authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, varnish

I'm drawing an architectural blank on good ideas of how to handle token authentication.

We have phone apps that generate REST requests to our backend API (rails).
Right now varnish is in front of our API and it's working great, however there's a gaping hole in how we handle auth: we *dont*.

I'm not looking to get flagged for asking for someone to solve it, I'm just asking from a high level how some have.

The phones create their device in the app via POST and get a *unique* token. They submit that token in all their other GET requests via `Authorization: OAuth {token}`. Our rails API handles this fine, but since the GETs are cached through varnish, we've hamstring'd it.

Due to performance we want to not cache each response *per* phone. The responses across the phones are all the same. If I were to add the token header to the hash in `vcl_hash`, that means that if 50 phones were to request `/a/1`, then we'd have 50 of the same items in cache, and the backend would get 50 requests. We'd like to avoid that.

I'm at a blank on how to authenticate the clients on a group level of some method.

Not sure if helpful:

- Varnish 3.0.7 is what we have. Not against 4, just havent.
- Every client goes through varnish, however we only care about User-Agent being android/ios. That part is done, anything else just goes straight to the API.
- Given the previous point, it's safe to assume that all clients that we would hash/cache would have the same *authorizations*. It's purely the auth token issue. ie. All clients with a token we would just check to make sure it's valid and give them the cached resource. There will *never* be different resources across the clients using tokens.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, I see a couple potential approaches.

1) You can set up a backend that does nothing but validate the user - have Varnish validate anything that has not been restarted, and only after validation return the cached resource.  Here's a good [blog post](http://monolight.cc/2011/04/content-authorization-with-varnish/) that gives some VCL to get you started.

2) This is more speculative on my part - you can use [ESI (Edge Side Includes)](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/esi.html) in Varnish to do the Auth.  What I'm not sure about is if there's a way to kill the request or pass a failing status code from within an ESI fragment.  If not, you'd end up returning the content even if the auth failed. Messy.

Comment: Any progress? Was this helpful?